# Text will not appear on top of Babylon.js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, babylonjs

I am making a scene with Babylon.js, which utilizes the canvas element.  I also want text to appear on top of this canvas, as it is set to take up the entire page.  I have tried to do this, and it works without the Babylon.js present, but whenever I put it together with the Babylon.js, the text either appears invisible, or only displays the text, and not the Babylon.js.  I have heard that the only way to bring a canvas drawing to the front is to code it after the element behind it, but this doesn't work for some reason.  Here's the code:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
            var canvas = document.getElementById('renderCanvas');
            var engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true);
            var createScene = function(){
                var scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
                var camera = new BABYLON.UniversalCamera('camera1', new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 5,-10), scene);
                camera.setTarget(BABYLON.Vector3.Zero());
                camera.attachControl(canvas, true);


                var light = new BABYLON.HemisphericLight('light1', new BABYLON.Vector3(0,1,0), scene);


                var sphere = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateSphere('sphere1', 16, 2, scene);
                sphere.position.y = 1;


                var ground = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateGround('ground1', 100, 100, 100, scene);


                scene.gravity = new BABYLON.Vector3(0, -9.81, 0);


                camera.ellipsoid = new BABYLON.Vector3(1, 1, 1);
                scene.collisionsEnabled = true;
                camera.checkCollisions = true;
                ground.checkCollisions = true;
                sphere.checkCollisions = true;
                camera.applyGravity = true;


            }
            var scene = createScene();


            engine.runRenderLoop(function(){
                scene.render();
            });


            window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
                engine.resize();
            });
        });

        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "67px Arial";
ctx.fillText("TEST", 10, 50);
```

Comment: Can you post some code and maybe a picture?

Comment: Sure just a second

Comment: Does engine.runRenderLoop() update all the time, like setInterval?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
engine.runRenderLoop(function(){
    scene.render();
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "67px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("TEST", 10, 50);
});
```

I don't know Babylon, but I assume that `runRenderLoop` is a render loop, ie. it renders the scene over and over (at whatever frame rate it decides). This would mean that as soon as your text is drawn over the Babylon scene, the Babylon scene renders the next frame, and draws over your text.

Comment: I tried this, but it freezes the camera and still won't display the text

Comment: Yeah, I looked and there are none

Comment: Is there any reason why you can’t just draw the the text in Babylon after all the other stuff?

Comment: Have no idea why it freezes though

Comment: yeah, I looked and there isn't

Answer (score 0):

Answer:  Using HTML as a way to display text in JS turns out to be a tad redundant.  When looking further into the Babylon.js documentation, I have found that the BabylonJS library has a built in GUI element That can be used to display text without HTML or other JS at all.  [Here is the link](https://doc.babylonjs.com/how_to/gui#position-and-size) to where you can find this if you're trying to do the same.